# show that unit $n$-sphere is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $S^n=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1})\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}: x_1^2+\dots+x_{n+1}^2=1\}$.

I want to show that unit $n$-sphere is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ this way:

Let
$A=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1})\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}: x_1^2+\dots+x_{n+1}^2<1\}$ and
$B=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1})\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}: x_1^2+\dots+x_{n+1}^2>1\}$.

Then I want use that the union of two open sets is open and the complementary of the open set is closed, hence $S^n$ is closed, but I cant understand how rigorously show that $A$ and $B$ are open.

Is it a bad path? What is the easiest way to do it (I mean not the shortness but using just as elementary notions as it possible).
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Show that the sphere is the zero set of a continuous function.

Comment: The preimage of $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$ at the continuous function $f(x)=\sum_ix_i^2$ are open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1.**

We have $A=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1})\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}: x_1^2+\dots+x_{n+1}^2<1\}= f^{-1}(]-\infty,1[)$, with $f(x)= x_1^2+\dots+x_{n+1}^2$ is a continuous function and $]-\infty,1[$ is open, so $A$ is an open set.

By the same way, we show that $B=f^{-1}(]1,+\infty[)$ is open.

So  $S^n=A^c \cap B^c$ is a closed set.

**Method 2.**

$S^n=f^{-1}(\{1\})$, with $\{1\}$ a closed set and $f$ the same function as in the Method 1 .